# dict2items requires a dictionary

Tags: ansible

I have the following values list:

```yaml
bind_zones:
- "test.com.":
    ttl: 3h
    allow_transfer:
    - "0.0.0.0/24"
    masters:
    - dnsmaster.test.com
    records:
    .....
```

I now try to call this values list like this:

```yaml
- name: configure zone databases
  template:
    src: zonefile.j2
    dest: "{{bind_db_dir}}/db.{{item.key|regex_replace('^(.*)\\.$', '\\1')}}"
    owner: "{{bind_user}}"
    group: "{{bind_group}}"
    mode: 0640
    validate: "named-checkzone -d {{item.key|regex_replace('^(.*)\\.$', '\\1.')}} %s"
  when: inventory_hostname in item.value.masters|default([])
  loop: "{{ bind_zones|dict2items }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{item.key}}"
  notify: reload-bind
```

Which fails with the error

> dict2items requires a dictionary, got <type 'list'> instead.

What is the correct way to use this then in my use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If dict2items requires a dictionary, let's feed it with a dictionary. For example, the play below works as expected

```yaml
  - hosts: localhost
    vars:
      bind_zones:
        test.com.:
          ttl: 3h
          allow_transfer:
            - "0.0.0.0/24"
          masters:
            - dnsmaster.test.com
        test.org.:
          ttl: 3h
          allow_transfer:
            - "0.0.0.0/24"
          masters:
            - dnsmaster.test.org
    tasks:
      - debug:
          var: item
        loop: "{{ bind_zones|dict2items }}"
      - debug:
          var: item
        with_dict: "{{ bind_zones }}"
```

The loops in the play are equivalent.